# Something strange when generating random matrices ( Eigen Library )

Tags: c++, matrix, random, eigen, random-seed

My intention is to stack, in *tmp*, matrices generated as **orth(randn(lenghtDim, dimsSubsp(iK)))'** (in Matlab notation)
I simulate nresample times this procedure and every time I compute the squared norm of *tmp* and save it in normVal. I tried different ways to generate these random matrices but their norm value is always the same (with Matlab I don't have this behaviour)!

Could you help me to understand this strange behaviour and to solve it? Thank you

```
Eigen::VectorXd EmpDistrLargSV(const std::size_t lenghtDim, const std::vector<std::size_t>& dimsSubsp, int nresample ){

 Eigen::VectorXd normVal;
 Eigen::MatrixXd tmp(std::accumulate(dimsSubsp.cbegin(),dimsSubsp.cend(),0),lenghtDim);
 normVal.resize(nresample);
 std::normal_distribution<double> distribution(0,1);
 std::default_random_engine engine (nresample );
    for (int i = 0; i <nresample ; ++i) {
        for (int iK = 0; iK < dimsSubsp.size(); ++iK) {
            std::size_t row_start=std::accumulate(dimsSubsp.begin(),dimsSubsp.begin()+iK,0);
            Eigen::MatrixXd myRandMat = Eigen::MatrixXd::NullaryExpr(lenghtDim,dimsSubsp[iK],[&](){return distribution(engine);});
            Eigen::JacobiSVD<Eigen::MatrixXd> svd(myRandMat, Eigen::ComputeThinU );
            tmp.block(row_start,0,dimsSubsp[iK],lenghtDim)=svd.matrixU().transpose();

        }
        normVal(i)=tmp.squaredNorm();
    }
    return normVal;
}
```

--- EDIT ---

What I'm trying to write in C++ is the following Matlab code

```
nb = length(dimsSubsp);
tmp = zeros(sum(dimsSubsp), lengthDim);

normVal = zeros(1, nresample);

    for i = 1:nresample
        for ib = 1:nb
            irow_start = sum(dimsSubsp(1 : (ib - 1))) + 1;
            irow_end = sum(dimsSubsp(1 : ib));
            tmp(irow_start : irow_end, :) =  orth(randn(lengthDim,dimsSubsp(ib)))';
        end
        normVal(i) = norm(M, 2)^2;
    end
```

To get the `orth()` , in C++ I compute the svd and then take the matrixU.

Comment: Two things: 1. You are constructing a new random engine with each function call meaning that it will be seeded exactly as before and will produce the same sequence of pseudo-random numbers. Always construct your random engine outside and seed it one. 2. The above is *not* the only reason your code produces the same value all the times. In fact, fixing the random number generation doesn't change anything. You have no programming but a math error.

Comment: I did it on purpose, to put the random engine inside the function.
What I don't understard is why at each iteration of external loop, normVal is always the same number. I tried to print tmp and at each iteration looks a different matrix, but its norm is always the same..
I added to matlab code I was trying to "translate" in C++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

Haha, I know what it is now. You are performing an SVD and looking at `U`, which is always (regardless of the input) a unitary matrix. A unitary matrix has the property that `U^T * U == I`, which implies that the norm (and squared norm) of each of its columns are exactly 1. Therefore, the squared norm of the matrix is going to be equal to the number of columns (the minimum of rows or columns in the case of your "thin" `U`), regardless of what random number generator you use.

Irrelevant information below:

Instead of `std::default_random_engine`, try `std::mt19937`. I'm not sure if it is important for you to use `nresample` as your seed, but you may want to try using something like `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count()`. Otherwise, I think your approach is similar to mine.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <random> 
#include <Eigen/eigen>

MatrixX<double> random_matrix(int rows, int cols, double min, double max, unsigned seed)
{
   std::mt19937 generator(seed);
   std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution(min,max);
   MatrixX<double> result(rows,cols);
   for(double& val : result.reshaped())
      val = distribution(generator);
   return result;
}

MatrixX<double> rando = random_matrix(20, 34, -30.1, 122.3, std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count());
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested me, but I still get the same result in normVal

Answer (score 0):

According to [default_random_engine documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/default_random_engine/) its de fault constructor creates [linear congruential engine](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/linear_congruential_engine/linear_congruential_engine/) which does simple increment and modulo starting from some seed.

Therefore random engine you use is deterministic.

This is why you get the same matrices and the same norm. Matlab is probably undeterministic.

Comment: How can I solve this problem? Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: [std::random_device](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device) is said in documentation to be non-deterministic. Try to use it instead of `std::default_random_engine`